# How to get reference of Array's item correctly (with ngModel)?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

There is my component model:

```
fields: Field [];

//where
export class Field { 
   key: string;
   value: string;
}
```

User can dynamically push/remove items of this model array:

```
pushField() {
    this.fields.push({ key: "", value: "" });
}
removeField(index: number) {
    this.fields.splice(index, 1);
}
```

My purpose is implementation of a validation: `value` of any `fields` item is required (must not be empty string):

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields; let i = index;">
    <input [(ngModel)]="fields[i].value" #field="ngModel" [name]=" 'fields['+i+'].key' "  type="text" required />
    <div [hidden]="field.pristine || !(field.errors && field.errors.required)" class="alert alert-danger"> Required error message </div>
</div>
```

It works at all but I get the following strange behavior:

- Sometimes error message is not hidden for the item that was just pushed (i.e. pristine rule is ignored)
- One item duplicates error message hiding state of other (i.e. if one item is empty then the error message of other is showed) - it happens seldom.

What can be a cause of this behavior? I think the reason is wrong getting a reference of field's item: `#field="ngModel"`(this code into iteration). So how I can get a correct reference?

Comment: Did you try using `trackBy`?

Comment: What should i do to be able to reproduce your issue in this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/DvgYLsGpq6lBAFNqnjd6?p=preview?

Comment: @yurzui, yes, I can not reproduce that issue in plunker. So the reason of it is not a wrong reference and this question is invalid

Comment: @yurzui I have found the way of this behavior: in the plunker code try to place template in form tag. So if you remove any item from fields array then the last but one input-item is treated Angular as new pushed item (copy its value, ng-classes). I have no idea about this issue

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476677/ngmodel-cannot-detect-array-changes-correctly