# ngModel cannot detect array changes correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

The component model:

```
private SomeArray = [{ key: "Initial" }];
```

User can add/remove items dynamically:

```
addField() {
    this.SomeArray.push({ key: Math.random().toString() });
}

removeField(index: number) {
    this.SomeArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Template markup:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
     <button (click)="addField()" type="button">Add</button>
 </div>

 <div *ngFor="let field of SomeArray; let i = index;">
     <input [(ngModel)]="field.key" #modelField="ngModel" [name]=" 'SomeArray['+i+'].key' " type="text" class="form-control" required />
     <div [hidden]="modelField.pristine || !(modelField.errors && modelField.errors.required)" class="alert alert-danger">
        Required error
     </div>

    <button (click)="removeField(i)" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
 </div>
```

This works untill user removes any item from `SomeArray`. If I add some two items initially:
[image]

and remove the one with 1 index:

[image]

then after adding another item Angular treat it as item has both 0 and 1 index (the new item "occupies" both two inputs):

[image]

(item with key 0.1345... is not displayed)

It's worth to noting items of `SomeArray` are as expected, but data binding fails. What can be the reason of it?

**Update**: Thanks to the comments of @Stefan Svrkota and @AJT_82 it's known for me the issue can be resolved by adding `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` to the needed input. But I couldn't stop thinking about the reason of the issue in my cause, without setting `standalone` option (there is unique value for each name attribute so it's excepted nothing wrong here).

Finally I have found that behavior occurs when  input elements are into `<form>` tag only - [Plunker sample here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DvgYLsGpq6lBAFNqnjd6?p=preview) (enclosing of template with form tag is the reason that issue).

Any ideas of this behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265761/using-ngfor-with-ngmodel-dynamic-data-wrong-behaviour

Comment: @Stefan Svrkota solved, thank)

Comment: @AJT_82 I think  `[name]=" 'SomeArray['+i+'].key' " ` returns unique name value (with index of iteration i)? am I wrong?

Comment: @Mergasov Nevermind what I was babbling about :D Yeah, ngModelOptions is a good solution here since I guess you don't really need the name attribute here in the form (I assume it is), as you are using two-way-binding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason why it happens is `ngFor` mixes `name` properties when you delete some item.

When you use `ngModel` inside `form` each `ngModel` control will be added to form controls collection.

Let's see what happens if we have added three items and clicked on `Remove` the second

1) Step1 - `SomeArray[1].key` exists in collection `controls`
[image]

2) Step2 - `SomeArray[1].key` has been removed from `controls` collection

[image]

3) Step3 - Html looks like

[image]

4) Step4 We are adding a new item

[image]

So `formGroup` returns existing item.

How we can solve it?

1) Don't wrap our controls in `form` tag

2) Add `ngNoForm` attribute to form

```
<form ngNoForm>
```

3) Use

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}
```

With all three solutions above:

- We can remove `[name]` property binding
- We can't use the built in Form group validation

**4)** **Use trackBy for ngFor**

**template.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let field of SomeArray; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

**component.ts**

```
trackByFn(i: number) {
  return i;
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/gyxxKvUeD5NryMqSHaqK)**

This way our built in form will work properly