# Angular 2 - Handling multiple checkboxes checked state

Tags: forms, angular, checkbox, ngfor

I'm building a registration form, and have to handle multiple checkboxes generated through *ngFor structural directive.

Template:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Response Type</label>
        <div class="col-lg-7">
          <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let type of client.responseTypes; let i = index">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="responseTypes" [(ngModel)]="client.responseTypes[i].checked" /> {{type.value}}
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

TS model object:

```
client.responseTypes = [
{ value: 'type1', checked: false},
          { value: 'type2', checked: true },
          { value: 'type3', checked: true }
];
```

The actual values behind the scene checked or unchecked are stored correctly. But, the checkboxes do not show the correct value.

- If one of the three objects.checked == false, all checkboxes will show unchecked
- Only if all three objects.checked == true, all three will be checked in the form.

[image]

I tried fiddling with `[value]="client.responseTypes[i].checked"` and `[checked]="client.responseTypes[i].checked"` on the input element, but to no success.

Any pointers in the right direction are massively appreciated.

Regards, Chris

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hoemtb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Wow, that is super weird... I have no idea what or how triggers the unwanted behaviour in my application.

Comment: @yurzui Problem was caused by the fact my template code was inside a <form> element. Apparantly it causes behaviour I do not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after trying to wrap my head around why my local application wasn't showing the result I wanted, I started to copy and paste my form-group out of the `<form></form>` element it was in.

Ta-daa, it works now.

> FYI: Placing *ngFor checkboxes inside a `<form></form>` element results in unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476677/ngmodel-cannot-detect-array-changes-correctly

Comment: Hi yurzui, thank you for your in-depth comment on that thread, helps out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is ok, well, you can do too

```
<input type="checkbox" name="responseTypes" [(ngModel)]="type.checked">
```

the problem is in other place (when you defined the client -I think you write some like this.client.responseTypes=...-), you can write

```
{{client |json }}
```

to check it

Comment: Thanks, but not helping. yurzui provided me with a stackblitz showing my exact code, and it's working on that platform. No idea whats going wrong with my app...

Answer (score 0):

In angular every model bind with name , means you need to give unique name to each Form elements`

For Example:

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Response Type</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let type of client.responseTypes; let i = index">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="type.id" [(ngModel)]="client.responseTypes[i].checked" /> {{type.value}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Object :

```
client.responseTypes = [{id: '1', value: 'type1', checked: false},
      {id: '2', value: 'type2', checked: true },
      {id: '3', value: 'type3', checked: true }];
```

And now Check :) Thank you

Comment: Hi Memon, I tried your suggestion. My HTML, wrapped in a <form> element with your solution does not seem to work for me. Thanks for your effort though!