# Remove item in *ngFor from *ngFor with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to remove item in `*ngFor` from `*ngFor`.

[image]

When I removed the reply 'test2',

[image]

and after I added an other reply, the 'test3' became empty.

[image]

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" ngNativeValidate class="mt-4">

  <div *ngFor="let content of contents; let indexContent = index; let firstContent = first;">

    <div *ngFor="let message of content.messages; let indexMessage = index; let firstMessage = first;">
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Text</th>
          <th class="text-right">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let reply of message.replies; let indexReply = index; let firstReply = first;">
          <td [innerHtml]='reply.id'></td>
          <td>
            <input type="text"
            id="{{indexContent}}-{{indexMessage}}-{{indexReply}}-reply-text"
            [(ngModel)]=content.messages[indexMessage].replies[indexReply].text
            name="[[indexContent]]-[{{indexMessage}}]-[{{indexReply}}]-reply-text">
            <br>
            <span [innerHtml]="contents[indexContent].messages[0].replies[indexReply].text"></span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span (click)="message.removeReply(reply)">Remove Reply</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <br>

      <span (click)="message.addNewReply()">
        Add Reply
      </span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

And my message model with different function to add reply, remove reply

**message.model.ts**

```
import { Reply } from "./reply";

export class Message {

    constructor(public id: number         = 0,
                public text: string       = '',
                public replies: any[]     = []) {
    }

    public setModel(obj) {
        Object.assign(this, obj);
    }

    addReply(new_reply) {
        this.replies.push(new_reply);
    }

    addNewReply() {
        let new_reply = new Reply();

        this.replies.push(new_reply);
    }

    removeReply(reply) {
      this.replies.splice(this.replies.indexOf(reply), 1);
    }
}
```

I reproduce my problem just here: Remove object from array in `*ngFor` in Angular

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clmi7d

Comment: link not working for me

Comment: @gyc https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clmi7d

Comment: Put code in your question.

Comment: @bryan60 it's done

Comment: don’t use filter, use splice instead. And try just feeding in the index directly rather than doing that index lookup

Comment: @bryan60 don't use filter ? where ?

Comment: Interesting behavior. Why do you use `contents[indexContent].messages[0].replies[indexReply].text` instead of just `reply.text` in the `ngModel`? Changing it doesn't fix this behavior, but it seems more foolprof to me anyway.

Comment: @JérémieChazelle You have filter in `removeReply` function.

Comment: You use filter to remove items from the array, removing items from an array isn’t the purpose of filter as it does not edit the original array. Use splice. You’re over complicating a lot in this code

Comment: @bryan60 it was a test, I updated my code with simple splice, no filter

Comment: @Senthe it was a test, I updated my code with simple splice, no filter

Comment: Try this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvul9b?file=app/app.component.ts See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476677/ngmodel-cannot-detect-array-changes-correctly

Comment: @Senthe I use contents[indexContent].messages[0].replies[indexReply].text instead of just reply.text to see the changement

Comment: @yurzui it's like good ! You added trackBy: trackByFn; ?

Comment: Yep, you found it fast)

Comment: @yurzui awesome ! Thx !!! Maybe you can post an answer ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use `trackBy` option to avoid [unexpected situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476677/ngmodel-cannot-detect-array-changes-correctly)

**html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let reply of message.replies; trackBy: trackByFn; 
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**app.component.ts**

```
trackByFn(i: number) { 
  return i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need here, is standalone ng-model option. Also, I would simplify `ngModel` and `innerHtml` bindings

```
    <input type="text"
        id="{{indexMessage}}-{{indexReply}}-reply-text"
        [(ngModel)]="reply.text"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
        name="{{indexMessage}}-{{indexReply}}-reply-text" />
    <span [innerHtml]="reply.text"></span>
```

Another option would be using `ngFor` `trackBy` as it was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47696672/3211932) by @yurzui, in that case standalone is not needed.

You also have an issue with `Reply.id`. As a temporary workaround you may try following approach:

```
let maxId = 0;
export class Reply {
    constructor(public id: number = 0, public text: string  = '') {
        this.id = this.id || ++maxId;
    }
}
```