# Why angular resets value for [(ngModel)] control?

Tags: angular

See that stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k5cq2e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

1. Press remove at the item 1 - item is removed, and the item 2 will be left
2. Press add - new item has been added and also item 2 has been reset to empty string

Why item has been reset? How to prevent such behaviour??

Comment: You can use `trackBy` option to solve it. To get more details check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476677/ngmodel-cannot-detect-array-changes-correctly

Comment: @yurzui thank you very much, if you want feel free to add an answer

Comment: I don't get the behavior you're describing. While `trackBy` optimizes performance so the components are not recreated, recreating the components shouldn't cause the model value to be lost. Ah, I think the problem you are facing is because the model value is actually updated only on `blur` by default (meaning when the input looses focus).

Comment: @AndreiTătar I have tried https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k5cq2e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html and with track by it works, also in link provided by yurzui in the first comment there is an explanation of default behaviour. The issue with name in the forms.